# Replace SOH character in string

Tags: c#, string, replace

I am reading a small MSWord document and storing its contents in a string.

There are SOH special characters included in this string. I would like to replace them with a placeholder string, like "#placeholder1" before they are written into a new text (.txt) file. Note that I am not wanting to modify/edit the MSWord document

I'm not sure if string.Replace would suit this or if I need to go a different route. It may just be the parameter I am using for the SOH character.

Suggestions?

Comment: How are you representing the SOH character?

Comment: \x01 is what I am currently using

Comment: I would have expected that to work, but try with `\u0001`. See [these docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664669%28v=VS.71%29.aspx). Also is there anything following that character in your search string that might be mistaken for part of the escape sequence?

Comment: It looks like each SOH is followed by a VT. The last SOH does not have a VT paired with it. Each SOH is on its own line

Comment: No I meant your search string. If you're searching for `"\x01AnotherWord"`, then the escape string is going to be interepreted as `\x01A` which is obviously not what you want. Might be best if you provide a complete code example in your question.

Comment: Do you mean Microsoft Word documents? These are not strings, and \x01 can have different meanings in a Word file depending on context. It is not safe to blindly replace bytes in a document. If you are trying to parse a Word file, use [Word automation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37600/Word-automation-Part-1).

Comment: @JamesHolderness - `text.Replace("\x01", "yay!");` is what I am currently using

Comment: @DourHighArch - I am using the codeproject here [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22738/Read-Document-Text-Directly-from-Microsoft-Word-Fi)

They assign the resulting text to a richtextbox control upon completion. `rtbText.Text = text;`

My current testing just involves taking the **text** and using a streamwriter to write it to a text file. The end result is that it includes the special characters, which is fine, I would just like to replace them as I will be parsing that text file later with another language

Comment: I'm out of ideas. Maybe try adding some debug code that echos out the ASCII values of the string to see whether it really does include SOH and that it hasn't been converted to something else.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no reason why what you're doing shouldn't work. Here's a minimal example that you can test on [ideone](http://ideone.com/cuPCoy):

```
using System;
public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        String s = "\u0001 This is a test \u0001";
        s = s.Replace("\u0001","Yay!");
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
```

The only other thing I can think you might be doing wrong, is not storing the result of your call to `Replace`.

Comment: That is essentially what I have. Come to find out though it looks like it may have been an issue with the word document I was reading. I replaced it with a copy I had elsewhere and the replace now works. Interestingly the ascii ouput on both files is the same...

[1]
[11]
[13]
[1]
[13]

I will accept this though as the answer as it certainly is correct. Appreciate your help James!

Comment: Thanks for the accept. I find it helps to come up with a minimal example, because it can narrow down the source of your problem. In this case it clearly wasn't the `replace` that was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function to read the content of Microsoft Word document (requires reference to `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word`):

```
public string ReadWordDoc(string Path)
{
    // microsot word app object
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application _objWord=null;

    // microsoft word document object
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document _objDoc= null;

    // obj missing value (ms office)
    object _objMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

    // string builder object to hold doc's content
    StringBuilder _sb = new StringBuilder();

    try
    {
        // create new word app object
        _objWord= new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

        // check if the file exists
        if (!File.Exists(Path)) throw (new FileNotFoundException());

        // full path to the document
        object _objDocPath = Path;

        // readonly flag
        bool _objReadOnly = true;

        // open word doc
        _objDoc = _objWord.Documents.Open(
            ref _objDocPath,
            ref _objMissing,
            _objReadOnly,
            ref _objMissing,
            ref _objMissing,
            ref _objMissing,
            ref _objMissing,
            ref _objMissing,
            ref _objMissing,
            ref _objMissing,
            ref _objMissing,
            ref _objMissing,
            ref _objMissing,
            ref _objMissing,
            ref _objMissing,
            ref _objMissing);

        // read entire content into StringBuilder obj
        for (int i = 1; i <= _objDoc.Paragraphs.Count; i++)
        {
            _sb.Append(_objDoc.Paragraphs[i].Range.Text.ToString());
           _sb.Append("\r\n");
        }

        // return entire doc's content
        return _sb.ToString();
    }
    catch { throw; }
    finally 
    {
        _sb = null;

        if (_objDoc != null) { _objDoc.Close(); }
        _objDoc = null;

        if (_objWord != null) { _objWord.Quit(); }
        _objWord = null;
    }
}
```